# Can't see navigation bar of UIPrintInteractionController(Swift) in Light mode

Tags: ios, swift, airprint, uiprintinteractioncntrler

Issue with light mode in AirPrint(Swift). [image: AirPrint Issue]

Is there any way to change the colour of the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this delegate method

```
- (UIViewController *)printInteractionControllerParentViewController: (UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController
{
 return self.navigationController; 
} 
-(void)printInteractionControllerDidPresentPrinterOptions:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController { 
// self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor redColor];
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
 // self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
 self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
}
```